# Create vertically centered horizontal line to fill width of title with padding in CSS

Tags: html, css

I basically need to create a title that has a vertically centered horizontal line filling up the width (left and right) but that also supports multiple text elements on the same line, e.g. to form something like:

**----- Alpha - Beta - Gamma -----**

This is what I have so far:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkZkt/)

Here, I have the demo working fine BUT it requires a background to work, this isn't a good solution since my background on my site is not a static single color (it's a fixed picture which doesn't move when you scroll).

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkZkt/1/)

So what I need to do is basically fix the first version to work like the second version but without using a background.

I thought of doing something like:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line-text">Some</div>
  <div class="line-gap"></div>
  <div class="line-text">Text</div>
  <div class="line-gap"></div>
  <div class="line-text">In a Line</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Where **.line** would be an auto width (to fill the left and right sides) and **.line-gap** would just be say 10px to show the line between the text.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Here is another demo, but I would prefer something that is more automatic rather than trying to set the position absolutely because it is for a responsive fluid design...

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMug3/)

Comment: Why not just use relative positioning on all the elements - http://jsfiddle.net/qMug3/1/

Comment: @user125697 added a variant of your code with a dashed line: http://jsfiddle.net/qMug3/4/

Comment: I don't want to use left: XX for each text element since I will use the same element for each text (i.e. all class="line-text" and not "text1" "text").

Comment: and also no background on the text elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a background, you could do a little trick using the `:before` and `:after` properties.

Here's the example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXCU8/12/), you can change the content/properties to whatever you like and it does what you've asked.

Example below.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li class="sub-menu-item" ><a href="#">Example</a></li>
<li class="sub-menu-item" ><a href="#">Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li.sub-menu-item:before,  li.sub-menu-item:after {
    content: "\2014 \2014"
}

li { 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: My first example uses :before and :after elements but they don't expand and fill like the second example. The second example is exactly what I want to achieve but without having to put a background on the text (and to keep it as a solid line, sorry my plain text example is misleading).

Comment: @dan2k3k4 I don't understand the problem - all you have to do is change what's inside content: to get what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/EXCU8/12/ - I'm not using a background or anything

Comment: It isn't exactly what I was looking for. The line should expand to 100% width of the container (so it's responsive for different screens/mobile) as well have some gap/padding before and after each word (or letter in the real user case). My original solution: http://jsfiddle.net/WkZkt/1/ - works well but requires background to be set. The others, I've not found a way to make them expand all the way across.