# Can this be accomplished with CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CQpv1Wm.jpg]

Can the line behind the text be accomplished with CSS only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create vertically centered horizontal line to fill width of title with padding in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654967/create-vertically-centered-horizontal-line-to-fill-width-of-title-with-padding-i) and also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985009/how-can-i-make-a-fieldset-legend-style-background-line-on-heading-text

Comment: Probably with css :before and :after selectors, and a bit of creativity.

Comment: no images whatsoever, or css with background images?

Comment: None of the solutions in the other issue would work for me. I have a double line (light grey/white), so I may have to use a png.

Comment: there really isn't any need for a png here; a simple CSS border will do the trick. See my answer.

Comment: That doesn't look like a double line, it looks like an inset or outset border.  All of the solutions in the questions Zenith linked are poor (either require multiple elements or a background image).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

HTML:

`<h2><span>Centered Header Text</span></h2>`

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #ccc;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
h2 > span, h2:before, h2:after {
    display: table-cell;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/2x1/f0f/fff&text=+) repeat-x center;
    width: 50%;
    content: ' ';
}
h2 > span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0 9px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jm4VQ/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985009/how-can-i-make-a-fieldset-legend-style-background-line-on-heading-text)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can.

No images, no tables, just two elements and simple CSS.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/URrdP/

HTML:

```
<div> <span>Text Here</span> </div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    font-size: 45px;
    border: #EEEEEE inset 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    height: 0px;
}
span {
    position: relative;
    top:-0.7em;
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

The key points here are that the outer element has an inset border and zero height and the inner element is positioned half a line upward so it sits on top of the outer element's border.

The other key point is that the inner element has a solid background color, otherwise the border line would show through. This means the technique will only really work successfully when you are placing it on top of a solid background; putting it on top of a gradient or an image may not work so well.

I may not have got the colors or the font sizing perfect for you in my example, but the principle should work perfectly fine for you.

CSS border `inset` may not be the best way to get a perfect colour match for you; if you need more fine-grained control of the colours you can specify individual colours for `border-top` and `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could do something similar with no images.

HTML:

```
<h1><span>Text Here</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
body, span { background: #ccc; }

h1 { text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #333; font-size: 20px; height: 10px; }
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisLTD/fvetd/

Answer (score 1):

Without images version (I'd prefer the display:table version though)

CSS:

```
body
{background:silver;}

h1
{text-align:center;color:white;font-weight:normal;position:relative;
line-height:1;text-shadow:0 1px black;font-size:34px;font-family:georgia, serif}

h1::before, h1::after
{width:100%;border-bottom:1px white solid;content:' ';
position:absolute;top:50%;left:0;}

h1::after
{margin-top:-1px;border-color:gray}

h1 > span
{background:silver;position:relative;z-index:1;}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>
  <span>
    Text Here<br>
    On Multiple Lines too
  </span>
</h1>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uqexar/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no HTML specification, I added in a couple of `span`s

```
<h1>
  <span class="wrapper">
    <span class="text">TEXT HERE</span>
    <span class="line"></span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    width:300px;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#333;
}
.wrapper {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
.line {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    background:#cecece;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e3e3e3;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    z-index:100;
}
.text {
    z-index:200;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This means the line will look like you specified with two greys.

http://jsfiddle.net/3q5he/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single element:

http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/vLwDf/

```
<h1>Heading</h1>

h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
    background-color: #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
}
h1:before {
    right: 0.5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
h1:after {
    left: 0.5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}
```

Origin: http://www.impressivewebs.com/centered-heading-horizontal-line/#comment-34913